# MySQL - Difference between two queries

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT clientid,totalquantity from clientquantity 
order by quantitydate desc) AS A GROUP BY clientid);
```

and

```
SELECT clientid,totalquantity from clientquantity group by clientid;
```

can someone please explain the difference between the 2 queries above. The result set is same in terms of rows counted. So, is there a difference between the 2 queries? For example, performance wise, or data difference?

The first query is used as part of a `LEFT JOIN` query with another table. I have removed that other table for simplicity in this post.

> **Is the above because the 2nd query needs to contain an ORDER BY as well and with SQL the only way to do that is to have do it like done
>   in 1st query? I have omitted ORDER BY from the 2nd query but it is
>   required in the 2nd query as well.**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d520f/1) to understand the difference between two queries of yours.

1. When you use order by your data by date in descending order and than
   group that data using clientId than it will retrieve all client data
   with latest by date.
2. If you directly use `GROUP BY` clause then it will fetch every first
   records from table by clientId.

Comment: i am only interested in the first row returned. MYSQL discards the remaining rows and hence i can get the first row. Do you see any issue with that approach?

Comment: Check my sql fiddle demo example which will give you the perfect idea about which was to be used when. If you want every first row then the second query is perfect but if you want data lasest by date then you have to use first query

Answer (score 0):

The first query `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT clientid,totalquantity from clientquantity order by quantitydate desc) AS A GROUP BY clientid);` has (what look to me) like redundant parts. The deepest part of the query (`SELECT clientId,totalquantity...`) gets all the information from the table itself ordered by quantitydate. The second part of the query is the `SELECT * FROM ...` which simply is saying "pull all the data out of the inner result set into my result set". The last portion is  taking that result set and grouping it by client id.

The second query `SELECT clientid,totalquantity from clientquantity group by clientid;` does almost the exact same thing, but much more succinctly: It grabs the clientid and totalquantity coluns and groups it by client id. *The only difference is that it doesn't sort it by the quantitydate descending*.

When executed they will essentially do the same thing (the row order will be different), but your database engine should be smart enough to have both have nearly the same performance as well. As for readability, I would use the second query and tack on `ORDER BY quantitydate DESC` before the group by statement so that it does the same thing as the first (unless you didn't want it ordered, of course).

Comment: "has like redundant parts" -- how they could be "redundant" if removing would change the result set?

Comment: "before the group by statement" --- it won't change anything. If you place `order by` right before `group by` - you won't get the same results as in the 1st query.

Comment: I feel that the SELECT * FROM (a result set) with no modifications could be removed. It could be stated SELECT clientid, totalquantity FROM clientquantity and then tack on the group by and sorting. Of course, I am probably missing something :p.

Comment: yep, you're missing something ;-) The nested is used to "fool" mysql and take the maximum `totalquantity` value for each `clientid` group - since `totalquantity` from the select isn't used in `group by` or in aggregate function - the first one will be taken (the biggest one)

Comment: Ah, so even though the result set is going to be the same in terms of data, the set is going to be sorted by whatever order it is found in the inner result set before grouping.

Comment: "Ah, so even though the result set is going to be the same in terms of data" --- no, not the same. The first guarantees the `totalquantity` to have the biggest value, in the second the `totalquantity` will be chosen "randomly"

Comment: @zerkms: They are redundant from a standard SQL view. A decent optimizer would throw the `ORDER BY` off the window (and then both queries would return equally nonsense results. Of course a standard parser would throw error with both of them :)

Comment: "Of course a standard parser would throw error with both of them" --- +1'd for this specifically )

Comment: MYSQL does not allow ORDER BY followed by GROUP BY. That is why that syntax is needed. As I said this query is part of a complex query involving multi inner joins and left joins. I have only pasted a part of it to break down a complex query into smaller part for understanding.